# Android não resolve dependências do Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebase

Estou tendo erro ao resolver as dependências do gradle:

Tento compilar e recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_prodDebugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0.
     Required by:
         tinc_project:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://nexus.poynt.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.0/firebase-core-9.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://nexus.poynt.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.0/firebase-core-9.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
      > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://nexus.poynt.com/content/repositories/releases/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.0/firebase-core-9.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://nexus.poynt.com/content/repositories/releases/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.0/firebase-core-9.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0.
     Required by:
         tinc_project:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://nexus.poynt.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/9.0.0/play-services-analytics-9.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://nexus.poynt.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/9.0.0/play-services-analytics-9.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
      > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://nexus.poynt.com/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/9.0.0/play-services-analytics-9.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://nexus.poynt.com/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/9.0.0/play-services-analytics-9.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Como consigo resolver este problema?

Answer (score 3):

A versão `9.0.0` dos pacotes `com.google.android.gms:*` e `com.google.firebase:*` são lançados diretamente no SDK.
Logo é necessário atualizar sua versão para as ultimas disponíveis.

No Android Studio:

- Click em Tools > Android > SDK Manager
- Selecione a tab SDK Tools tab
- Selecione e instale Google Play Services (rev 30) e Google Repository (rev 26).
- Sincronize e Compile seu projeto.